# jq convert timezone in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, timezone, jq

I have a query as below:

```
dump=$(jq -j --raw-output '.aggregations | ."2" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."5" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."3" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."4" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."8" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."6" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."7" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."9" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."10" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."11" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."12" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."13" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."14" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."15" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."1" | ."hits" | .hits[] | ."_source" |
                                           "\(."@timestamp")" | "\n"))))))))))))))' <<< "$cl_report")
echo -e "${dump}" >> report.csv
```

timestamp is ISO8601 format.

I want to convert the **timestamp** from UTC to Madrid time.

What I want is something like **this**:

```
dump=$(jq -j --raw-output '.aggregations | ."2" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."5" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."3" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."4" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."8" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."6" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."7" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."9" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."10" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."11" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."12" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."13" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."14" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."15" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."1" | ."hits" | .hits[] | ."_source" | "\ 
                                       (."@timestamp") as $tstamp | "TZ Europe/Madrid" date -d $tstamp" | \n"))))))))))))))' <<< "$cl_report")
```

Bash throws error complaining about " and ' etc etc.

What is the correct way of doing this conversion?

**Ok. It seems there is a bug with jq 1.5. strftime etc does not read TZ properly in this version.**

jq 1.6 can help:

```
report_dump=$(TZ=Erope/Madrid jq1.6 -j --raw-output '.aggregations | ."2" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."5" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."3" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."4" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."8" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."6" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."7" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."9" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."10" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."11" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."12" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."13" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."14" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."15" | .buckets[] | "\(.key),",
                                       (."1" | ."hits" | .hits[] | ."_source" | .["@timestamp"] | sub(".[0-9]+Z$"; "Z") | fromdateiso8601 | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z"), "\n"))))))))))))))' <<< "$cl_report")
```

As shown above, I piped the stripped timestamp to fromdateiso8601 to get seconds and then piped into strflocaltime that utilizes TZ to get the local time.

Comment: Include a [mcve]

Comment: Include your source json data and what the transformed output should look like.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right tags?  [jquery] is a javascript library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, jq's handling of local time zones has been problematic
and you may need to adapt the following according to the specifics
of your version of jq (i.e. version number and platform).

Here's an illustration using the TZ environment variable, e.g.

```
TZ=Europe/Madrid jq -n -f program.jq
```

where program.jq contains:

```
{"@timestamp": "2020-05-04T18:02:13Z"}
| .["@timestamp"]
| fromdateiso8601   # converts to seconds
| gmtime
| strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
```

Output: `"2020-05-04T19:02:13CET"`

Note: %Z becomes CET.

Comment: Great. We're getting there. Apart from that my time is like {"@timestamp": "2020-05-03T22:41:34.237Z"}. Those miliseconds 237 does not let the format of the timestamp be matched to fromdateiso8601 input. How do you resolve this?

Comment: Strip them off, and add them back again if needed.